# Gradle cannot find google services plugin

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I've seen a lot of other questions on SO about this topic, but they're all dealing with things I don't think are relevant to my situation, so I'm making a new question.

In my android app, I am hoping to utilize firebase as my database. However, after copying the google services json file into my 'app' folder, and adding the necessary dependencies in my 'build.gradle' file, it's giving an error, saying 'plugin with id "com.google.gms.google-services" not found'. I'll include the code for my build.gradle, please let me know if I made a mistake somewhere!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xlr8.jackson.doctrineoropinion" 
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {

    }
}
```

**Notes:**

I have tried several options such as:

- move `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to the bottom in buildscript/dependencies
- Change `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you downloaded the most current Google repository using the sdk manager?

Comment: I don't know. I have the google-services.json file, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8 This can help you

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ` why do you have this line? What tutorial told you to put this there?

Comment: I was following the tutorial on firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you doing it wrong way its not way to add google play services.You need to compile google play service in project level build gradle first like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and then add libraries you need in app level build.gradle like this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'   


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
```